# Which mobile browsers support <track> when using html5 video

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm looking for a resource on what browsers currently support the  tag. What alternatives are there? and is it in any way usable on a mobile phone, I have a hard time seeing that the text would be readable. On tablets with bigger screens it would make more sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best table I've found so far for summarizing  support across browsers: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/#texttrack

Answer (score 1):

[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) is excellent for finding out what browsers support what. This is the link for the [video tag](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video)

Comment: Exactly, but there is no reference for the track tag.